# jquery UI Lightbox not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Hi i'm using the following jquery UI Lightbox this code is not working in IE
 refered from http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/jquery.ulightbox/demo/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ulightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ulightbox.css" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 uLightBox.init({
  override:true,
  background: 'white',
  centerOnResize: true,
  fade: true
 });

 $('#alert').click(function() {
  alert('Hello');
  });
 });
 </script>
```

is there any option to work out this in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: the "uLightBox" plugin (or "ClassyLightbox", as it's currently named) doesn't work with Internet Explorer (at least with versions 8 and 9), since it throws a JavaScript error.
However, I've managed to make it work this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.classylightbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.classylightbox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function alert(val){ 
            ClassyLightbox.alert({ title: 'Alert', text: val, rightButtons: ['OK'] }); 
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            ClassyLightbox.init({
                override: false,
                background: 'white',
                centerOnResize: true,
                fade: true
            });

            $('#alert').click(function() {
                alert('Hello World');
            });
        });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
         <input id="alert" type="button" value="Click Me" />
    </body>
</html>
```

In my example I've used the latest version of the plugin, downloaded from [here](http://www.class.pm/?retrieve=process&did=NzUuaG90bGluaw==).
Then I've set `override` to false and redefined the `alert()` function to invoke the `ClassyLightbox.alert` method.
If you're using an older version of the plugin, you should do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alert(val){ 
    uLightBox.alert({ title: 'Alert', text: val, rightButtons: ['OK'] }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    uLightBox.init({
        override: false,
        background: 'white',
        centerOnResize: true,
        fade: true
    });

    $('#alert').click(function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    });
});
</script>
```

The drawback of this solution is that you can no longer change the background color; in other words when `override` is set to false, the `background` property is ignored.